# How to add on python

Tags: python, addition

I am trying to make a program where I can ask someone's age - then tell them that on their next birthday they will be `x` many years old.

for example:

python = "How old are you?"
answer = "17"

python = "On your next birthday you will be 18 years old".

that is the program which I am trying to make however I am stuck on how to add `1` to the age of the person

Comment: Could you post some code? Adding `1` should be extremely simple.

Comment: I am new to Python, please could you explain what you mean by post some code. Sorry, I am not very familiar with python yet

Comment: try A="On your next birthday you will be" + str( int(B)+1) + "years old"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing a program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22078917/writing-a-program)

Comment: age=input('How old are you?')
print ("On your next birthday you will be" + (age+1) + "years old")        This is what I have tried so far however it does not seem to work.

Comment: 'age' seems to be an invalid syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
age += 1
```

or

```
age = age + 1
```

Make sure you are [casting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) the user's input from a string to an integer.

Comment: probably OP meant age represented by string, so age = str(1+int(age))

Answer (score 2):

In order to increase `age` by one, you need it to be an integer. 
Try:

```
age = int(input("How old are you? ")
age += 1
print("On your next birthday you will be" + str(age) + "years old")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
age = input('How old are you?')
print('On your next birthday you will be' + str(int(age)+1) + 'years old.')
```